# Docker daemon not starting after adding --insecure-registry option

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to run a docker daemon on ubuntu 14.04.  I have a private registry running on the same host on port 5000. The registry is running on http, not https, which is fine for my purposes.

When I try to start the docker daemon with `sudo service docker.io start`, I see this error in syslog:

`kernel: [9200489.966734] init: docker.io main process (9328) terminated with status 2`

`/etc/default/docker.io` has just this one option

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 192.168.0.100:5000"
```

When I try to start the daemon by hand with `sudo docker.io --insecure-registry 192.168.0.100:5000 -d` I get an error message saying `flag provided but not defined: --insecure-registry`

I've read the documentation on this, and it **looks** like I'm doing everything right, but clearly I'm missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you are running docker v1.2 not v1.3 - you might need to update your docker version, take a look at docker -h and see if the flag is available.

Comment: I'm using version 1.7 and getting the same error message.